# WP_Query count of different meta key values

Tags: php, wp-query, count

I need to get count of different values of meta_key:

Let's say I've got meta_key `$class` & there's only three different values: `1`, `2` & `3`.

```
//My WP_Query 
$ads = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'ads', 
    'meta_key' => 'ads_class', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
)); 

    if ( $ads->have_posts() ) :

    //Do stuff


//Now I need to know how many have ads_class of "1", "2" and "3" - all as different vars
```

Comment: You have a loop. Just count as you go. That is a pure PHP problem though and off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over the posts and bump the count based on the value of `ads_class`:

```
$ads_1 =
$ads_2 =
$ads_3 = 0;

while ( $ads->have_post() ) {
    $ads->the_post();

    switch ( ( int ) get_post()->ads_class ) {
        case 1 :
            $ads_1++;
            break;
        case 2 :
            $ads_2++;
            break;
        case 3 :
            $ads_3++;
            break;
    }
}

$ads_1; // Number of "1" ads
$ads_2; // Number of "2" ads
$ads_3; // Number of "3" ads
```